# Patch Values Reactive Forms Array of Array Angular 2

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "name": ""
 "parts": [
   {
    "name": "partname1",
    "description": "description 1"
    "messages": [
      {
       "text": "text 1"
       "sender": "sender 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "partname2",
   "description": "description 1"
   "messages": [
     {
      "text": "text 2"
      "sender": "sender 2"
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Based on this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
Using this code:

```
setParts(parts) {
  const partsFormGroup= parts.map(part => this.fb.group(part));
  const partsFormArray = this.fb.array(partsFormGroup);
  this.myForm.setControl('parts', partsFormArray);
}
```

patchValue works fine for parts properties: name & description.

How to patchValue to messages?

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.validator is not a function
```